# Laravel whereDoesntHave() - multiple OR conditions

Tags: laravel, relationship

In Laravel 4.2 I have a model called Product with many-to-many relationshis to other models like Country or Category. I want to filter out products that are "incomplete", which means they have no connected countries or no connected categories. I can use `whereDoesntHave()` method to filter out one relation. When I use it two times in one query it creates `AND` condition, but I need `OR`. I can't find `orWhereDoesntHave()` method in API documentation. I can't pass multiple relations as arguments because it expects first argument to be a string.

I need something like this:
`$products = Product::whereDoesntHave('categories')->orWhereDoesntHave('countries')->get();`

Is there any way to achive `whereDoesntHave()` with multiple `OR` conditions?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use `doesntHave` and specify the boolean operator:

```
$products = Product::doesntHave('categories')->doesntHave('countries', 'or')->get();
```

Actually you only need `whereDoesntHave` if you want to pass in a closure to filter the related models before checking if any of them exist. In case you want to do that you can pass the closure as third argument:

```
$products = Product::doesntHave('categories', 'or', function($q){
    $q->where('active', false);
})->doesntHave('countries', 'or')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed `doesntHave()` while reading API. Your first code example is just what I need.

Answer (score 30):

Since Laravel 5.5 there is an [orWhereDoesntHave](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) function.

You may use it like this

```
Product::whereDoesntHave('categories', function($q){ //... })
       ->orWhereDoesntHave('countries', function($q){//...})
       ->get();
```

From you example it seems that you are not using a where clause, so you may just use

```
Product::doesntHave('categories')
       ->orDoesntHave('countries')
       ->get();
```

Answer (score 5):

Let’s say we have Authors and Books, with 1-n relationship – one Author can have one or many Books. Here’s how it looks in app\Author.php:

```
 public function books()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Book::class, 'author_id');
    }
```

Now, what if we want to show only those Authors that have at least one book? Simple, there’s method has():

```
$authors = Author::has('books')->get();
```

Similarly, there’s an opposite method – what if we want to query only the authors without any books? Use doesnthave():

```
  $authors = Author::doesnthave('books')->get();
```

It’s not only convenient, but also super-easy to read and understand, even if you’re not a Laravel developer, right?

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
Product::whereDoesntHave('categories')->doesntHave('countries', 'or')->get();
```

**Laravel Source Code:**

whereDoesntHave https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Builder.php#L654
calls
https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Builder.php#L628
internally.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I missed `doesntHave()` method and its second parameter.